# Pop up message if blob is detected, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, popup, blob, message, matlab-cvst

I am working on a fire detection program in MATLAB, and I have a blob detection as part of it. I would like to ask how to put a pop up warning message when a blob has been detected?

I want to have a warning message as soon as there's a fire.

This is my code for the shape inserter, or the boxes for blob detection.

This part is outside the loop:

```
 detector = vision.ForegroundDetector(...
    'NumTrainingFrames', 5, ...
    'InitialVariance' , 30*30);

blob = vision.BlobAnalysis(...
    'CentroidOutputPort', false, 'AreaOutputPort', false, ...
'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);


shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor', 'White');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
```

This part is inside the loop:

```
   fgMask = step(detector, maskedRGBImage);
    bbox = step(blob, fgMask);
    out = step(shapeInserter, thisFrame, bbox);
    step(videoPlayer, out);
```

Comment: can you provide a small section of code with input image that we can actually run on our own? That would be much easier to help to. Thanks!

Comment: have you looked up matlab's inputdlg function:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html ?  You can setup an _if loop_ that will trigger the pop-up gui when a blob is detected

Comment: @rowe did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example I'm assuming that if a blob is detected it will equal 1 (you can change my code to fit whatever output you currently have for when a blob is detected).

[image]

```
if blob == 1;
 inputOptions = {'Fire Detected!'};
 defSelection = inputOptions{1};
popup = bttnChoiseDialog(inputOptions, 'Warning!', defSelection, 'Warning!');
fprintf( 'Fire Detected - "%s"\n',inputOptions{popup});
 else 
continue
end
```

You can download `bttnChoiseDialog` from the FileExchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37261-generalised-question-dialog--questdlg-/content/BtnChoiseDlg/bttnChoiseDialog.m

hope this helps

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK. THANK YOU! :D